# Calculating terms in an arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I don't know how I'd go about actually solving this problem. Using brute force I was able to determine there are between $5000$ and $5300$ terms added to get the result, but I want to know how I'm supposed to solve this:

> If the sum of the arithmetic series $7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 + \dotsb$ is $25\,613\,712$, then how many terms were added up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial sum of the arithmetic series, $s_n$, is given by 
$$s_n = \frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$$
But $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$, where $d$ is the difference between each term, 2 in this case. So the equation becomes $$s_n = \frac{n(2a_1+(n-1)d)}{2}$$
And so you're looking to solve the equation,
$$25,613,712=\frac{n(14+2(n-1))}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

You need to come up with a formula for each term.  Depending on what math you are familiar with, you can see that it is a linear progression, so the same amount gets added each time.

After figuring out the expression for each term, you can set up a summation and use the facts such as $$\sum_{n=1}^{x} n = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$$ and other summation rules.

**ETA:**
Okay, with pre-calc rules...

You could think of $$7+9+11+\dots+x=25613712$$ as $$(7+0*2)+(7+1*2)+(7+2*2)+\dots+(7+n*2)=25613712$$

This can be simplified to $$(n+1)7+[2+4+6+\dots+2n]=25613712$$ $$(n+1)7+2[1+2+3+\dots+n]=25613712$$

Do you know the equation for the sum of the first n positive integer?

Comment: I'm in pre-calc at the moment, with no idea what a summation is.

Comment: @Portali5t If you don't know what a summation is, then how are you expected to know what a series is?

Comment: @Portali5t a summation **is** a series, just another name for it.  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^x n$ is just a simpler way of writing $1+2+3+\dots+x$.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I was unaware summation notation=sigma notation.